Cannot connect locally to containerized Kafka, Error: Missing close-
I believe I have a configuration problem that I don't seem to be able to get around. Currently I have a containerized Kafka broker and I want to connect to it locally. However, when I try to connect through a simple python script I am seeing this odd error from the script:
rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:['localhost:19092/bootstrap]: ['localhost:19092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve '['localhost:19092': Missing close-']'

Here is my current broker setup on my docker-compose.yml
  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0
      container_name: zookeeper
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: "2000"

  kafka-broker-1:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.0
      container_name: kafka-broker-1
      hostname: kafka-broker-1
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
      ports:
        - "19092:19092"
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka-broker-1:19092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-broker-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:19092
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8084"
        KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
        KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9991

and here is the python script I run after the startup to connect to, just a simple producer making a test message
from confluent_kafka.cimpl import Producer

def setup_kakfa():
    producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': ['localhost:19092']})
    result_dict = producer.produce("my-events", "my-test-message")
    producer.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_kakfa()

Other notes, I know that port 19092 is open, I'm able to hit it through
nc -zv localhost 19092
I use Colima as my container manager, I'm running on MacOS
I've tried different ports, I've ensured that kafka is running in the docker container as per the logs. I looked at other stackoverflow questions like this one . I seem to have everything setup correctly, but my client apparently does not think so. Hopefully someone can help me see what I'm missing.
Thanks for your help.


Python property should be just a string, not a list 2) KAFKA_LISTENERS should use 0.0.0.0 for the host listener to expose it externally. Netcat doesn't properly test that, but kcat -L does


Yes, those were the two things I needed to fix, in particular the Missing close -] error was from the fact I should be using a string and not a list. Also note: you cannot use localhost you must use 0.0.0.0. Localhost does not resolve correctly. Thank you again for you help!

localhost does resolve ; otherwise the second advertised listener wouldn't work. But when used on the regular listener, only connections within the container are allowed

Just highlighting @OneCricketeer answer below as it worked for me but appears as a comment

Python property should be just a string, not a list
KAFKA_LISTENERS should use 0.0.0.0 (not localhost) for the host listener to expose it externally.

